# Ignoring warnings in non-project files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, suppress-warnings

I just turned on all warnings (`/Wall`) and treat all warnings as errors (`/WX`). I suddenly went from 0 warnings to 1329 error-warnings.

The thing is, 99% of those warnings are not in files I've written. Part of them are in the standard library, while others are in libraries I'm using with my project.

How do I tell Visual Studio to perform this kinds of checks only for files that I've written (which are a part of the project directly) while ignoring everything else?

Note that all my own source files will be within a single folder, as will any library includes (but not the same as my source files).

EDIT:
I've realized I can wrap all includes I don't want checked between two pragmas, for example:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0) // Ignore warnings in non-project files.
#include "volk.h"
#include "glfw3.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#pragma warning(pop);
```

However, in this case, I have several warnings present in file `xmemory` which are still being reported. They appear in function `_Adjust_manually_vector_aligned`, but I don't know where to go from here.
Note that this warning appears even if I wrap my whole (and only) file in the pragmas above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While wrapping includes in `#pragma warning(push, 0)` and `#pragma warning(pop);` will work for flags `W0` to `W4`, `Wall` seems to contain warnings that are not affected by the pragmas above. It is by design:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/891a02d2-d0cf-495a-bcea-41001cf599de/pragma-warningpush-0-cant-disable-wall-warning-on-visual-studio-2017?forum=vcgeneral